# How to read JSON Extractor in JMeter using while controller?

Tags: jmeter

My scenarios is: I have created an object and I have to pull the logs for that object. Log contains 10 IDs each have status like `running` or `finished` etc.

I want to check status for each ID, if it is `finished` then need to run next sampler; if failed then, exit the loop.

I tried `while controller`  with condition `${__javaScript("${IDstatus}" !="FINISHED")}`. Loop never exit, even status is `finished`.

Comment: Can you please share the JSON object details?

Comment: I cannot post the screenshots now. But I was able to achieve your requirement. After extracting the response using `JSON Extractor`, Add `For Each Controller` and enter the `input variable` of JSON extractor, `Start Index` as `0` and `End Index ` leave blank. Enter `returnVar`in the `Output Variable Name`. Now, add `If controller` and enter the condition `"${returnVar}" == "finished"`.Inside the `If Controller`place your requests. If the condition satisfied, respective sampler will be executed, else not. Let me know if this helped you. Also the same you can achieve using `JSR223 Sampler` also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution you purposed seems not working. It simply skips the whole foreach controller. I"m keeping foreach controller in second thread group by using global variable in request. 
It works fine with while controller the only issue is its not reading the condition and keep running the request even meet the condition. 
Is this possible to run foreach and if controllers together? Even condition worked if put match number= 1 in json extractor. But i want to check status for all 10 ids.

Comment: This is my sample JSON `{
 "phew": [ {
   "status": "running"
  },
  {
   "status": "running"
  },
  {
   "status": "finished"
  },
  {
   "status": "running"
  },
     {
   "status": "finished"
  },
     {
   "status": "finished"
  },
     {
   "status": "finished"
  },
     {
   "status": "finished"
  },
     {
   "status": "finished"
  },
     {
   "status": "running"
  }
 ]
}`, when I designed the flow I am getting the response as shown in here. http://imgur.com/a/UnkpB It is triggering the next request, only if the status is `finished`, else it is skipping.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response contains `finished` string, and your are comparing it with `FINISHED`. Strings in JavaScript are **case sensitive** so `x` != `X`

[image: JavaScript String Comparison]

So my expectation is that if you change your While Controller condition to

```
${__javaScript("${IDstatus}" !="finished")}
```

your While Controller will start working as expected.

References:

- [JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)
- [JavaScript Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)
- [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter)

Comment: So here is the settings. condition is ${__javaScript("${Status}"  !="FINISHED")} and json expr $..[0].id match numbers -1.Screen Shot 2017-05-04 at 10.23.02 AM. Status string is FINISHED

Comment: sorry exprs is $..[0].status